# I need to create a calendar for community service projects

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'd like to use google calendar to create a public calendar that is only editable by certain members but viewable by all.  I am part of a non-profit (Rotary club) and one of the big issues we have is that clubs from around town have no idea what events / projects are happening in each other's respective clubs.  Is this possible to do using Google Calendar?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. This i swhat my google turned up. https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083?hl=en

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.